# My SD Card gets corrupted every time my phone reboots or shuts down

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, file-system, storage

I have a 32GB SD card, however, every time I mount it into my phone (Huawei Y5II), it shows a message that the SD card is corrupted and I should reformat it.

I backed up my files to my PC, and formatted my sd card. After that, the SD card finally worked.

However, every time my phone is rebooted or shuts down, the SD card just gets corrupted again.

Meanwhile, I found another solution without formatting, by using `CHKDSK` in command prompt, which did work, but it's still the same every time the phone reboots or shuts down and back, it says SD card is corrupted!

I have tolerated this problem for a year now.

Now I think because of this, I experience more issues with my SD card. Like some files suddenly turning into 0 bytes, some files getting missing, files being renamed, etc.

Should I replace my sd card(or phone) with another one? If yes, do you have any suggestions on what brand or model?

Comment: Have you tested the sd-card that it really has 32GB flash? There are cards on the market that claim to have 32GB bit only contain 16GB or less flash. Such a card could explain why it alway sis getting corrupted. Use a tool like `h2testw` to test the sd-card after formatting it.

Comment: Seems like an exceptional case, Android should un-mount SD card cleanly on shut down and run `fsck` (equivalent to Windows' `chkdsk`) on device boot.

Comment: It's more likely that your SD card came corrupted. Have you tried with another SD card?